# g/pattern/d but check first

Tags: ex-mode, global-command

I'd like to use Ex mode `:g/pattern/d` to delete most (but not all) of the rows containing `pattern`, but I want to see each one first and confirm before deleting, similar to `:s/pattern/foo/gc`. Is there a way to do this, in Ex mode or otherwise?

Comment: Try `:help :g`.

Comment: Thanks! That answers the second question

Comment: @JoshFriedlander please avoid asking multiple questions in one post! I’ve edited the second out for you.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want to do is to use the `:s` command inside your `:g` command:

We know that we can delete a line, with a confirmation using the following substitution:

```
:s/.*\n//c
```

This will replace all the characters (`.*`) *and* the next end of line character (`\n`) with nothing, effectively deleting the line. The `c` flag at the end of the substitution prompts for a confirmation.

Now [`:h :g`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Ag) tells us that the command `:g` takes a pattern and a command. The pattern is up to you to choose but the command can be the one we used before, making your `:g` command like this:

```
:g/pattern/s/.*\n//c
```

Replace `pattern` by your own pattern and you are good to go.

---

*EDIT* As Luc pointed out in the comments, this solution has some flaws: If you have consecutive lines matching the pattern only the first one will be handled.

A solution could be to use `:g/pattern/s/.*\|.*\n//c` but this will leave empty lines instead of deleting them completely. These remaining lines could be handled with `:g/^$/d` but that require to have no other empty lines in the buffer.

If you have empty lines in the buffer, you could replace the lines to be deleted with a marker `:g/pattern/s/.*\|.*\n/deleteme/c` and then delete the lines containing this marker with `:g/^deleteme$/d`.

Comment: The `:g/pat/s/.*\n/c` solution doesn't work with consecutive lines which shall be removed. `:%s/.*|.*\n//c` works though.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes ago, on SO, I've posted a solution to have a `:global` command which asks for confirmation before executing anything (`:delete` in your case): https://stackoverflow.com/a/46830106/15934

It's a *little* bit convoluted :D. It's [shipped with my library plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/commit/09262a723e70c9bcfcd54e791664a12d6f334e5a), and it can be used with

```
:ConfirmGlobal/pattern/d
```

Note: unlike the `:g/pattern/s/.*\n//c` solution, the confirmation is global, and it doesn't skip consecutive lines that shall be removed.

In the end, the only vanilla solution that I'm aware of, and that works in all situations (consecutive lines, first line (see Q/A on SO)) is

```
:%s/.*pattern.*\n//c
```

It's not `:global` with *confirm*, it's `:substitute` hijacked to remove entire lines, with *confirm*.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I see also now that my question is an exact dupe of that one

Comment: It's a dupe indeed... but not on the same site... :D

Comment: Ah, good point...

Comment: @JoshFriedlander This answer might deserve to be the accepted one, I completely missed the potential consecutive lines issue :)

Comment: Yeah. @LucHermitte's comment adapting your solution is maybe the best, plus its vanilla Vim.